# Configure MobileFirst Push SMS Settings Parameters (to,text)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

i'm using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 8.0.0
refer to this link [Push SMS Settings](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_push_sms_settings_put.html)

where i can define toParamName and textParamName in this request

this is the configuration:

 `{
  "port": "80",
  "programName": "/sendsms",
  "host": "xyz.com",
  "name": "SMSGateway",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "encode": "false",
      "name": "toParamName",
      "value": "to"
    },
    {
      "encode": "false",
      "name": "textParamName",
      "value": "text"
    },
    {
      "encode": "false",
      "name": "SenderName",
      "value": "Support"
    },
    {
      "encode": "false",
      "name": "UserName",
      "value": "xyz"
    },
    {
      "encode": "false",
      "name": "Password",
      "value": "xyz"
    }
  ]
}`

Note : push notifications working fine but sms notifications still not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can define toParamName and textParamName as part of parameters array in the JSON.

{
  "host" : "xyz.com",
  "name" : "TestGateway",
  "**parameters**" : [
    {
      "encode" : "true",
      "name" : "TestKey",
      "value" : "TestValue",
      **"toParamName" : "TestKey",
      "textParamName" : "TestValue"**
    },
    ...
  ],
  "port" : "80",
  "programName" : "/sendsms",
}

Thanks.

Comment: just push notifications working fine but sms notifications still not working